# Deleted single file, after reboot it's back

Tags: filesystem, uninstall, files

I have a file "Zkousky.ics" (calendar file, exams) on my desktop. Whenever I remove it, however, after reboot the file is back. I used several methods of removing, but the file is always coming back with its original creation date & time it was first downloaded (so it can't be stuck in download loop or something like that).

I tried to remove it via:

select -> <kbd>Del</kbd> (moves file to Trash)

select -> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>

`rm Zkousky.ics`

`sudo rm Zkousky.ics`

But still, after reboot, the file is back.

**EDIT**

I found out, that reboot is not necessary. This morning 7:52, after I previously set it's rwx permissions to  000, it was recreated anew and the original 000 file is missing. In this exact time (7:52) I log out of my session and log in back.

The only log from today is `Xorg.0.log`, where I found nothing concerning files (as excepted).

Comment: Mh... does the system shutdown properly? does it so a check of the file system on reboot? Is your desktop shared on a network with other machines or a server?

Comment: It shutdowns properly,  that's where I am sure. On startup, there is only a background check of filesystem, without the notification below the loading dots. My desktop is not shared, I don't even have dualboot, no netwrok sharing, nothing.

Comment: If there is a file system check, it might be that it repairs the file system, thus making it up to a stable version (previous). I suggest that you go on a live system and manually check all the involved partitions.

Comment: ok, I am going to try it

Comment: But to add - this is the only file, which persists. All the others are OK, where they should be.

Comment: tried moving the file somewhere else instead of only deleting it? Maybe you have a tool/script that recreates the file each time? With a cp -p it woult protect creation date etc. that's why it would always stay the same. Try searching your filesystem after that file with `find / -name Zkousky.ics`

Comment: `find...` returned two locations - desktop AND trash

Comment: Welp so it seems it is recreated each time? Grep your personal files after the content of Zkousky.ics - `grep -iRl "Zkousky.ics" /home/user` if that doesn't show anything maybe try going on a complete search of the system  `sudo grep -iRl "Zkousky.ics" /`

Comment: You could `chmod 000 Zkousky.ics` and see what complains. First. record the permissions.

Comment: @waltinator I followed your instruction. The file has been recreated with rw for me and r for others. The orgininal 000 file is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled this calendar in `gnome-calendar` app and the file stopped being recreated. Thus I assume it was created by this application every time it started.

Thank you all for your help.